# Constructor Parameter issue C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a constructor for a class that takes in a bool, a pointer to an array, and string.

```
TheConstructor(bool theBool=true, int *theArray=0, std::string message="0");
```

Is this the correct way to write it in the header file? My program isn't compiling right now because of a "undefined reference to "the constructor" and to other member functions".

What could be causing this also? I checked and in main.cpp I #included "Class.h" and defined every memberwise function that needed to be defined that was stated in "Class.h" I wrote in "Class.cpp"

Comment: You don't have a name for your bool. But the error shows that you haven't defined the constructor anywhere. I mean, the example you give is only the declaration, not the definition.

Comment: Can you show your class declaration and definition?"

Comment: And please could you show some real code? I take it that your actual class isn't named `TheConstructor`?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you didn't name your class `TheConstructor` :) If you have class `C` you can declare its constructor almost as you did - you forgot to put the name of the `bool` argument:

C.h:

```
#include <string>

class C
{
public:    
    C(bool b = 0, int *theArray = 0, std::string message = "0");
};
```

C.cpp:

```
#include "C.h"
C::C(bool b, int *theArray, std::string message)
{

}
```

Comment: The semicolon in C.cpp is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter's name is not specified, but that probably wouldn't cause the error you're encountering:

```
TheConstructor(bool=0, int *theArray=0, std::string message="0");
```

You probably want to do something like this:

```
TheConstructor(bool flag=0, int *theArray=0, std::string message="0");
```

However, without seeing the definition, there is not much else I can say about it. It's difficult to predict what else could be wrong by simply looking at the declaration.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that. It actually is defined properly

Comment: In that case it's going to be difficult to guess what's wrong. What does your definition look like in the cpp file?

Comment: In a prototype you don't need names for the parameters.