# Class issue with main C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I created my header file for a class and #included "theclassname.h" in main.cpp but when I try to compile I get "undefined reference to "ClassName::TheConstructor(bool, int*,  std::basic_string, std::allocator >)""

I coded the constructor and a function called "ClassName::start" inside of my Classname.cpp file but for some reason it is giving this undefined reference issue for this start function and for my destructor which is also coded in my cpp file. Every call I make in main to a function that was coded inside of the header file doesn't trigger this error but every call made to a function coded in my .cpp file triggers this.

I've seen a lot of posts about this but I've coded them properly with the correct parameters and return types and made sure the function name was the same as the one defined in the header file. What else could be causing this besides misspelling something because I've checked for that over 10 times.

Thanks

```
#ifndef THECLASSNAME_H
#define THECLASSNAME_H
#include <iostream>

class TheClassName {
 public:
   TheClassName(bool theBool=true, int *theArray=0,
        std::string message="-1");
~TheClassName();
void start();
void setBool(bool theBool) {aBool=theBool;}
 bool getBool() {return aBool;}
 void setMessage(std::string message) {mssg=message;}
 std::string getMessage() {return mssg;}
 std::string getHello() {return hello;}
private:
int *anArray;
bool aBool;
std::string mssg;
std::string hello;

void aFunction1(bool);
void aFunction2();
void aFunction3();

void aFunction4();
};

 #endif
```

Sorry Everyone just fixed it! In my makefile I did

```
exec1: main.o classname.o
     g++ -o exec1 main.o
```

Instead of

```
exec1: main.o classname.o
     g++ -o exec1 main.o classname.o
```

Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, you should post your code (or at least, a simplified representative version of your code).

Comment: It sounds like the .cpp file isn't part of your project. If you add it to the project, the compiler and linker will find the function definitions.

Comment: I think you should have rephrased/edited your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386144/constructor-parameter-issue-c)

Comment: You should use $^ in your linking rule to grab all the files on the RHS of the rule: ie. g++ -o exec1 $^

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like you're getting the error at the linker phase.  Are you also compiling the file that you have the C++ class definition in and not just including the header file?  You need to have a separate C++ file with the function definitions for you class, compile this file as well and include the object file in the linker command line so you don't get your undefined reference errors when you link the final executable.

Comment: Technically you don't need a separate file, but you definitely should.

Comment: Post your command line you are using for linking the final executable.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your code and also post the build command and output, if possible.

This is a linkage rather than compilation problem and it sounds like the compilation unit containing your constructor and destructor declarations have not been linked into the executable - in other words, the linker can't find your functions.